# Como faço para salvar a saida de uma REGEX em um novo arquivo

Tags: javascript, node.js, regex

```
const dirfile = 'BIG_DATA.HTM'
const reg = /(\<td .*)/g
const fs = require('fs')

const myReadStream =fs.createReadStream(dirfile,'utf8');


myReadStream.on('data',(chunk_)=>{

    var myReturn = chunk_.match(reg)

    //console.log(typeof(myReturn)) // -->>  returns all of My REGEX as object

    console.log(myReturn)  // -->> Returns every object of My REGEX that i nedd to write in another file 

}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Segundo a [documentação](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/match#Return_value), o retorno do método `match`, quando a regex tem a flag `g`, é um **array** com todas as ocorrências encontradas (no caso, um array de strings).

Então `myReturn` é um array, e basta percorrê-lo para obter os *matches* e usar [`createWriteStream`](https://nodejs.org/en/knowledge/advanced/streams/how-to-use-fs-create-write-stream/) para escrever seu conteúdo em um arquivo:

```
const entrada = fs.createReadStream(arquivoEntrada, 'utf8');
const saida = fs.createWriteStream(arquivoSaida, 'utf8');

entrada.on('data', (chunk_) => {    
    var myReturn = chunk_.match(reg);
    myReturn.forEach(function(trechoEncontrado) { saida.write(trechoEncontrado + '\n'); });    
});

saida.end();
```

---

Apenas um adendo: a regex busca por `<td` e em seguida temos `.*`, que é "zero ou mais caracteres". Só que o ponto corresponde a [qualquer caractere, exceto quebras de linha](https://www.regular-expressions.info/dot.html), e o [quantificador](https://www.regular-expressions.info/repeat.html) `*` é, por *default*, ["ganancioso"](https://www.rexegg.com/regex-quantifiers.html#greedytrap) e tenta pegar o máximo de caracteres possível.

Isso quer dizer que a regex vai pegar desde o primeiro `<td` que encontrar, e depois vai pegar tudo até a próxima quebra de linha (ou seja, dependendo do conteúdo do arquivo, ela pode pegar mais do que somente a tag `td`). Se o objetivo era pegar somente o `td`, aí já foge um pouco do escopo da questão, e vai depender de como está esse HTML (pois usar regex para *parsing* de HTML [nem sempre é a melhor solução](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1732454)).

Comment: Legal funcionou!!!!

Comment: const saida = fs.createWriteStream(arquivoSaida, 'utf8');
const entrada = fs.createReadStream(arquivoEntrada, 'utf8');

entrada.on('data', (chunk_) => {

  var myReturn = chunk_.match(reg);
  myReturn.forEach(function(trechoEncontrado) { saida.write(trechoEncontrado + '\n'); });

});

Comment: apenas tive que tirar o saida.end();